# Sefarim on iyun mehalachim?

Tags: talmud-gemara, torah-study, talmudic-methodology

Are there any sefarim that methodically elaborate a particular Iyun mehalech (method)? For instance, the Brisker Derech by Moshe Wachtfogel provides insight into the brisker mehalech albeit to a terse extent. Are there any other sefarim that achieve a similar, more in-depth elaboration? In others words, a dissection of the method, how it works and how it should be applied.

Comment: https://www.academia.edu/8159644/An_Analysis_of_Darchei_HaLimud_Methodologies_of_Talmud_Study_Centering_on_a_Cup_of_Tea

Answer (score 1):

I once came across an obscure pamphlet on how to learn Gemara, with an approbation from R' Yaakov Kaminetsky z"l. He writes that while it is best to learn how to learn from experience, the pamphlet could be useful for those who did not have time, etc. He clearly indicated that the best way to learn is through actual learning. I believe the same would apply to methods of iyun. They are best acquired by studying under a Rabbi who has mastered his method and learning with him, and no book could accurately convey the method.
In addition, such a book would probably be misleading, because it would by necessity focus on the differences and not the commonalities, although the differences are relatively small.